# Different permalink styles to same page

Tags: wordpress, mod-rewrite, permalinks

I have the following URL's that I want to point to the same resource:

```
1) mydomain.com/basename/category-name/page-name1/
2) mydomain.com/basename/page-name1/
```

URL#1 works and URL#2 goes to 404.

How would I rewrite URL#2 to include a default category so the link works? Or is there a better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are planning to redirect all pages with format #2 to #1 then you can use below RewriteRule, also assuming `category-name` will be fixed.

```
RewriteRule ^/basename/([a-zA-z-_]+)$ /basename/category-name/$1 [NC,L,R=301]
```

Comment: Close enough, thanks! I did change the rule to this:

`RewriteRule ^basename/([a-zA-z0-9-_]+)$ /basename/category-name/$1 [NC,L,R=301]`

Added 0-9 because numbers are valid in slugs.  Also, I had to remove the '/' in `^/basename`.  I'm not sure why, does anyone?

Comment: @KurtSerge if you are targeting your rule from root of your domain then you should add `/` else not.

Comment: Another point to add.  The above answer won't rewrite if there is a trailing `/` on the URL.  Change to: - `RewriteRule ^/basename/([a-zA-z-_]+)/?$ /basename/category-name/$1 [NC,L,R=301]`